# remove background-color on hover in css from mapbox maps

Tags: css, hover, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am working on mapbox maps https://jsfiddle.net/kpcxqo9s/embedded/result which on hover gives the purple background color.

The CSS code which I have used in the entire fiddle is:

```
.box {
  width: 300px
}
.riding
{
}
  font-weight: bold
p, h1, #controls li label {
          font-family: nexa,arial,helvetica;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
p {
  font-size: 14px;
}
#controls li label {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.mapboxgl-canvas:hover {
background-color: #0000ff !important;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to do in the fiddle so that on hover it doesn't show any background color. At this moment, 
it is showing purple.

This is what **I have added in the code but it didn't work**.

```
.mapboxgl-canvas:hover {
background-color: #0000ff !important;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/hover-styles/

Comment: @brooksrelyt I had a look on the link but it didn't help much because I am not using both events and feature states in the code. Let me know.

Comment: You have a space between `:` and `hover` - it should be `:hover`

Comment: The rule you wrote has incorrect syntax, use `.mapboxgl-canvas:hover `

Comment: @Adrift I have corrected in the fiddle but I can still see hover.

Comment: I understand the code is bit unorganized. I am wondering if you can let me know where do I need to have a look in the code in order to remove the hover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the color in this part of the code (line 313-319):

```
// Change style on 'featureEnter'
stopsInteractivity.on('featureEnter', featureEvent => {
    featureEvent.features.forEach((feature) => {
        feature.color.blendTo('#9278d1', 100);
        feature.width.blendTo(16, 100);
    });
});
```

to `transparent`, there wont be a hover-color.
The code will look like this, then:

```
// Change style on 'featureEnter'
stopsInteractivity.on('featureEnter', featureEvent => {
    featureEvent.features.forEach((feature) => {
        feature.color.blendTo('transparent', 100);
        feature.width.blendTo(16, 100);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have awarded you the bounty. I will let you know if I have any question.